# What is the meaning of "some" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does `some` mean in the following sentence? Does it has a meaning similar to `hardly any`?

```
Some consensus has been reached regarding the theoretical basis for
measuring the cost of travel time.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. it does not mean hardly any. 
It means an unspecified amount - more than none

Normally a bit, not all but some

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some